# Login System won't redirect new users to right page

Tags: php

Working on a game & I've added a feature to give users "home coordinates" when a user registers, it inserts a set of random coordinates to the database, along with all their other information, and then logs in the user.

The login system will redirect the user to the proper page, unless they are a new register, in which case it just directs them to 0,0. I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
    function login($username, $password)
    {
    $password = $this->passwordEncryption($_POST['password']);
    $sql = "SELECT count(uid), uid, homeX, homeY FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password";
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam('username', $_POST['username']);
    $que->bindParam('password', $password );
    try{ 
        $que->execute();
        while($row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
        {
            if($row[0] == 0)
            {
                $error = 'who do you think you are?';
                echo $error;
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $row[1];
                $x = $row[2];
                $y = $row[3];
                $index = "index.php?X={$x}&Y={$y}";
                return $index;
                //* Start the Session Timer
                $_SESSION['SS'] = time();
            }
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e) { echo $e->getMessage();}   
}

    function registerUser($password, $username)
{
    if($this->checkUsername($username) == 'chr')
    {
        header('location:index.php?error=nameC');
    }
    if($this->checkUsername($username) == 'short')
    {
        header('location:index.php?error=nameL');   
    }
    if(!$this->checkUsername($username))
    {
        header('location:index.php?error=taken');   
    }
    else
    {
    if(strlen($password) == 0)
    {
        header('location:index.php?error=pass');
    }
    else
    {
        $password = $this->passwordEncryption($password);
        $x = rand(-16, 16);
        $y = rand(-16, 16);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, homeX, homeY) VALUES (:username, :password, :X, :Y);";
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO bank_accounts(balance, fuel_cell, energy_cell) VALUES (10000,575, 575);";
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO user_upgrades(science, technology, economy, religion, military) VALUES(1,1,1,1,1)";
        $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $que->bindParam('username', $username);
        $que->bindParam('password', $password);
        $que->bindParam('Y', $y);
        $que->bindParam('X', $x);

        try{
             $que->execute(); 
             $que->nextRowset();
             $que->nextRowset();
             $this->login($username, $password);
             }

             catch(PDOException $e){}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where have you raised the error messsage ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking why new registers are always redirected to the cordinates of 0,0. It's most likely because the table doesn't have any value for that new user and will be a 0 in the database for the homeX and homeY columns in the database. It's very hard to tell exactly since we don't have any way of knowing if you are setting those values when the user registers since your code only shows the login.

I would also like to note, any code after a return will not be executed. Inside of the `else` statement where the user is validated as logged in, you return before the session.

```
return $index;
//* Start the Session Timer
$_SESSION['SS'] = time();
```

The session will never be set.

EDIT Update. You didn't bind the values properly.

```
    $que->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $que->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $que->bindParam(':Y', $y);
    $que->bindParam(':X', $x);
```

Comment: I thought i included the registration function as well. my bad.